# Converting the metadata of an image to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, image, metadata, jpeg

How can I read the metadata of a JPG image in Java using `BufferedImage`, and then encode it as JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MetadataExtractor can be used to extract metadata like Exif, IPTC... and more,  http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

The following snippet will print metadata found in file:

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
Iterable<Directory> directories = metadata.getDirectories();
Iterator<Directory> iterator = directories.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Directory dir = iterator.next();
    Collection<Tag> tags = dir.getTags();
    for(Tag tag: tags) {
        System.out.println(tag.getTagName() + "  " + tag.getDescription() + " " + tag.getTagTypeHex());
    }
}
```

This snippet uses the latest release candidate, http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/downloads/detail?name=metadata-extractor-2.5.0-RC3.zip&can=2&q=

At least that's a start with the extraction, which I believe is the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, dealing with [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) is a problem as it contains only visual raster image data.  When a `BufferedImage` is created from JPG data, all of the Exif/IPTC/Jfif/etc metadata is stripped off.

So you'll need to deal with the original JPG data, and proceed as detailed by Kennet.

The *metadata-extractor* library doesn't generate JSON directly, so you'll need to find another library to provide this.